# Difference between var and Class class in object creation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Its a silly question, however shocked to see different behaviors. Learning a lot.

Lets say I have two classes below

```
Class A
{
 public void Display()
 {
 }
}

Class B : A
{
 public void Display()
 {
 }
}

Class C : B
{
 public void Display()
 {
 }
}

Class Final
{
 static void Main()
 {
  var c = new C();
//  B c = new C();  

 }
}
```

My doubt is, both of the above gives different results. May I know `B c = new C()` creates object of B or C? What I understood is, it creates object of B. Then why we say `new C()`? I agree with `C c = new C();` But I thought, `B b = new C();` creates object of B. Where we use this style? Only when utilizing runtime polymorphism? (Overriding methods)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When declaring a variable with the [`var` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383973.aspx), the compiler infers the type of the variable from the right-hand side of the assignment. In particular, it uses the type the expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator (`=`) evaluates to.

Therefore, for your declaration

```
var c = new C();
```

, the variable `c` will be declared as type `C`.

If you want `c` to have any other type, there are basically two options:

- Either indicate the type of `c` explicitly: `B c = new C();`
- Alternatively, you can change your right-hand side expression to be recognized as the type of choice: `var c = (B)(new C());`

---

As for your more detailed questions:

- `B c = new C()` creates an instance of type `C`. That is what `new C()` does. The fact that variable `c` is typed to `B` only means that the compiler will assume that `c` has any properties and methods of type `B`, but not necessarily of type `C`. Likewise, you are allowed to assign not only instances of type `C`, but also instances of type `B` to `c` at a later time.
- Indeed, you can use this style when you are not sure whether `c` will at some point reference an instance of type `B`, rather than exclusively instances of type `C`.

Comment: Thank you Mapper. But I didn't understood B c = new C(); It creates object of C but of type B? I really do not understand its significance in my case above. I am just learning and trying to understand why we use like this. Real time scenario.

Comment: @Divine: A *variable* contains a *reference* to an *object*. The *type* of a variable is a *restriction* on what kinds of objects the variable may refer to. When you say `B c`, that means `c` is a variable that can only refer to objects **that are compatible with** type `B`. Since `C` is a class derived from `B`, it is compatible with type `B`, so you can store a reference to a `C` in a variable of type `B`.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you so much for helping me understand, that is a compendious and easy explanation :). I get it now :) :) Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 3):

`B c = new C();` is equivalent to `B c = (B)(new C());` the compiler implicitly convert `new C()` to `B` that is legal because `C` derive from `B`. `var c = new C();` simply is compiled as `C c = new C();` the type is infered from the value.

Take a look at this:

```
class B : A
{
    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
}

B c = new C();

c.Display(); // write C not B
```

Comment: Alessandro, thank you that made me understand it. So "B c = new C();" means we can access ONLY the public objects of B? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you have only access to the public interface of `B`, but you really have the behavior of `C`.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry again Alessandro, what do you mean by "behavior of C". Can you give me one small example of what you are saying with an inline code please.

Comment: Thank you so much Alessandro, I got this now :) Thank you so much for helping me understand :) :)

Answer (score 2):

`var` uses type inference to infer the type of the variable from the compile-time type of the expression you initialize it to.
Since `new C()` is of type `C`, your `var` is equivalent:

```
C c = new C();
```

Since your `Display()` method is not virtual, which method is called depends on the compile-time type of the expression you call it on.

Comment: Thank you SLaks. But B c = new C(); I do not understand it.

Comment: @Divine: You have a variable of type `B` referring to an object of type `C`.  You need to understand how polymorphism works.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

Comment: SLaks, sure, I will read this link you gave, thank you so much, now I got a good idea too.